# Microphone connection diagram

Tags: audio, microphone, mems-microphone

I am trying to replicate project Jasper of raspberry pi. Currently I am using a USB to audio converter (shown in image below) and a regular PC mic. However the audio reception range is very small. So, I am planning to make my custom mic with opamp to amplify the sound signal.

This is the wiring of the mic (which confused me actually):

[image]

Pins labelled '1' are GND. However 2 and 3 tend to produce similar output. (I was assuming GND, VCC, Analog OUT kind of stuff so that I could replace the mic with the red modules shown in the bottom left part. They are [ADMP-401 MEMS mics along with an op-amp](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9868)).

Here are the waveforms that I got after randomly shouting at the mic while connected to laptop. I took the readings from Pin 2 and 3.

[image: Pin 2 reading]

[image: Pin 3 reading]

This is what I want to do:

Use the breakout board to be the mic and that USB to audio converter module (because raspberry pi doesn't have a mic-in) to provide a audio-input to the raspberry pi. The reason I want to use the breakout board rather than regular mic is "lack of good audio reception range".

This is what I think I should do to get it working:

1) Connect GND of breakout board to Pin - 1.

2) Connect VCC to USB 5V supply after using a 3v3 voltage regulator.

3) Connect AUD to pin 2 or 3 whichever tends to work.

One more discovery that I should share:

Before plugging in the mic, the voltages at pin 2 and 3 float around 4.8V but as soon as I plug the mic in, the voltage drops down to 3.7V.

Any suggestions from you guys will be quite helpful.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: What do you mean "the audio reception range is very small"?

Comment: I want to be able to speak from other corner of the room and the module should get the voice signal. Right now it works at a 1-feet range. That's why i planned to use an opamp to amplify the sound signal. @NickJohnson

Comment: What microphone were you using? Is the input on that device a line in, or a mic in? If it's a line in, you will need a preamp.

Comment: I agree with Nick Johnson,you will need a preamp for line in,also the audio signal is same in both the channels,I once worked with piezoelectric mic,for it I had provide biasing with Opamp.But as my mic was specially piezoelectric its output was voltage,in your case it may be current ,so suggest you should try a preamp.

Comment: I think that you will have a hard time to pickup a voice from across the room. 1 feet range sounds about right to me. I think the only solution is a proper directional microphone and even then I doubt if you will get a clear signal. It has nothing to do with amplification but all about acoustics and such. Have you noticed that on TV, sound studio's etc they place the microphone really close to a person. And if they point the mic elsewhere, the sound is gone. Yes, our ears are SO much better at this than microphones.

Comment: @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie - I read about Amazon echo and also found [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAX9LBJeHo8). I think what I want to achieve is something like this. If Alexa can hear from that far while playing music, I guess I should be able to implement Jasper in a quiet room. What do you say?

Comment: Ok, that seems to work indeed. But I bet that this device has multiple (omnidirectional ?) microphones, uses automatic gain control for each microphone, uses digital signal processing to cancel echos (many cellphones also use this). So I think there will be a lot of "additional intelligence" behind the microphone. Our ears work in the same way, your brain is also capable of advanced signal processing.

Comment: [This](https://d3nevzfk7ii3be.cloudfront.net/igi/aPGKZyHMX62WHQjP.huge) is the audio input circuit. [More details here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Amazon+Echo+Teardown/33953). I was wondering if they use digital signal processing or simply hardware signal processing to do all this. I always tend to believe that processing done on hardware is much faster and this is a case where we need realtime speed. @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie

Comment: I guess it will be a combination of the two. Hardware processing can be less flexible. But a DSP loading a program and but processing in hardware. The distinction between the two is getting less clear these days ! Also, for audio it can be that software processing is fast enough and can easily be updated. What appears "realtime" to you can be "slow" in CPU time, they're much faster than we are (doing calculations I mean). Don't underestimate the power of modern mobile CPUs.

Comment: But back to your problem, what I think might help is a circuit that amplifies only when needed. Sort of a level control so that the audio signal to the RPi remains at a proper level at close range and at a distance. Something like an AGC (automatic gain control) chip for audio.

Comment: Thanks @IC_designer_Rimpelbekkie - I think I can continue reading from here to learn more about the topics you told me about and try to implement them somehow. Thanks a lot.

Comment: My pleasure ! As a bonus, maybe this is a usefull AGC IC: http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/audio/MAX9814.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typical USB sound cards have an earphone jack and a microphone jack.  Since it works with your microphone, it is set up to deliver power to the electret microphone - hence the 4.8 Volts when open.  That is to say, the sound card is delivering DC Voltage to your microphone.

The microphone input of a sound card can't supply much current, but it is enough for a small transistor amplifier.  If fact, electret mics all have a single FET transistor amplifier attached to them - the signal from the mic itself is very high impedance and requires that little amplifier to deliver low impedance signal.  You might stretch a point and find a low power op-amp that will work with 3.8V and damn near zero current, but I bet your pocket book will say "ouch" if you go that way.

Picking up a voice from across a (normal sized) room shouldn't be a problem, though, even without a preamplifier.  The mic can pick it up easily, and the sound card will digitize it.  What you hear has got relatively little to do with it, however.  It might well pickup and be capable of recording a voice that you can't hear when played back through the speakers.  You can amplify the signal digitally, however.

The sound card samples at 16Bits, which gives you a lot of room to amplify things digitally.  All you need to do is multiply the incoming samples with some number to amplify the signal.  Need 20dB of gain?  Multiply your samples by 10.

A better microphone shouldn't be neccessary, unless the one you've got is just utter crap.  I use a 20 year old electret mic from an old Toshiba laptop for my experiments - it can pick up voices from all across the room, even if I can't hear them on playback through the speakers.  A little digital gain, though, and all is good.

If you actually do go the preamp route, you will probably need to consider using an automatic gain control.  Cranking up the amplification until a voice from across the room gives you a full scale recording means that noises closer to the microphone will overload it and you'll just get a distorted mess.  Again, digital amiplification can save your bacon.  An AGC in software isn't that hard, so just take advantage of the 96dB range of that sound card and do the amplification digitally.

---

Mmmf.  Completely ignored the MEMs mic.

You might try connecting your MEMs mic like an electret with a simple transistor amp.  It might work, since the data sheet say the module only needs 250µA at 3.3 Volts.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1AeYd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You might have to diddle with R1 and C1 (different values) to make it go.
R1 might need to be bigger, maybe C1 could be smaller.

---

Looking at your linked picture of the Echo, it would seem that they are using multiple mics to eliminate noise and possibly track the voice source (for better noise reduction and to separate voices.)
The tear down shows a Texas Instruments DM3725 processor, which combines a DSP and an ARM core in one unit.  I expect the Echo uses the DSP core for all of the audio processing, and the ARM does the internet and user interface parts.

Comment: I was able to retrieve 67.8 mA current from the USB, I often have heard that it can go upto several hundreds of milli amphere,but practicality works in my case I had to use pre-amplifiers,I wonder about the whether FET gate is connected to the piezoelectric mic diaphragm,that changes the resistance in that case it would a current out device?I thought is was the voltage across the mic which changed the bias voltage to generate audio s/g.

Comment: It is the voltage across the mic that generates the signal.  It just such a high impedance signal that you really have to have the FET there as an impendance converter/amplifier.  I've never seen an electret mic in use that didn't have the little FET attached to it.  Not saying they don't exist, just saying that all the ones I've seen (even little naked 1/16 inch diameter mics) have the amp built in.

Comment: Fixed amplification will be an issue as you correctly pointed out. However I am planning to make something like OK Google, SIRI, Cortana or Amazon Echo. So, it will require realtime audio input (well realtime is better, I guess). And all this will be done on a raspberry pi because project Jasper is available which I am using. I wanted to go for hardware amplification because it is simple and fast. Do you think AGC software would be a good idea? Another hardware tweak is to use i2c controlled resistors to change gain on the go which seems easily doable. @JRE

Comment: AGC in software is trivial, at least if you are used to doing DSP work.  In fact, I would almost be that Jasper includes something of the sort.  You're not the first person to want a longer range of voice detection than "right in your face."

Comment: Thanks JRE. I will carry on my research from here. Seems like software AGC seems to be the way to go. I will try out the circuit you made for me (thanks again for that). I will post an update if I find something (good or bad).

Comment: One more request since you seem to be the guy who really knows this topic deeply. [Here](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Amazon+Echo+Teardown/33953) is the teardown of Amazon Echo which is much similar to what I am trying to make. Can you take a look and suggest how they are doing it. Most certainly I won't be able to do that but I might find that knowledge helpful.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack, Any final update on this?

Comment: @gvelascoh - sorry, but no. My intention was to make a cheaper alternative to amazon echo mic set but my approach was wrong. Echo uses an array of mics with hardware and software for noise cancellation and other features which improve the sound reception. The way I wanted to do was to have one or two mics with higher amplification. This won't be nearly as good as what echo has. I had to abandon the project altogether.

Answer (score 2):

The jacks are standard 3.5mm [mini-phone plugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)), otherwise known as tip-ring-sleeve jacks. They're not powered; as you observe the sleeve is ground, but the tip and ring are the left and right stereo channels.

What you describe ought to work, assuming the breakout board you're using provides enough amplification. The critical question is what input levels the USB device expects; microphones output very small signals, and if the USB device expects a line level input, you will need a great deal of amplification. You can connect the output from the microphone module to both ring and tip - 2 and 3 in your diagram - for a mono mic.

Bear in mind that whatever you do, the inverse square law applies - as you move away from the microphone, amplitude will decrease rapidly, far more rapidly than you might otherwise expect.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I opened up the regular mic and found nothing but a simple electret mic hooked up with some wires. So I am pretty sure the ADMP-401 will produce a better output than that electret. However I was worried about the VCC and output connection.

Answer (score -1):

The voltage drops cause the wire heats up and the microphone wire wound also heats up hence the voltage drop. The use of ethernet wire dramatically changes the micrphones output ... Its like yer mic on electronic steroids.
K take care and keep wath for the signs.